# Linq to SQL insert stored procedure exclude first row from inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server responsible for inserting records into the database:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Sp_Add_Item_Decription]
    @orderid int,
    @itemid int,
    @qty decimal(18, 2),
    @price decimal(18, 2)
as
    insert into [ResturantDB].[dbo].[ItemDescribtion] ([OrderID], [ItemID],[Qty], [Price])
    values (@orderid, @itemid, @qty, @price)
```

I used Linq to SQL to generate the below code but when I execute this code, if the datagridview contains one row it isn't inserted into the database, but if the datagridview contains more than one record then all records are inserted except the first row. I don't know what is the problem. I need to insert all the datagridview records.

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DTL;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            resturantDataContext addorderdes = new resturantDataContext();
            addorderdes.Sp_Add_Item_Decription(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                               Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
                               Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
                               Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
            addorderdes.SubmitChanges();
        }

        RadMessageBox.Show("RECORD ADDED!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Maybe you should consider debugging your application before asking us...

Comment: Also SubmitChanges is not needed when you only use the context to call a stored procedure. You don't need to create the context every time, just move the context outside to for loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
```

use

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
```

In this way you get the last row too.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop termination is on:

```
i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
```

This will always be one less than the number of rows in the data grid.

Just replace it with:

```
i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
```

Also as Adrian Iftode points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241741/linq-to-sql-insert-stored-procedure-exclude-first-row-from-inserting/37241900#comment62012776_37241741) you don't need to recreate the context on every iteration of the loop and you don't need to call `SubmitChanges` as your stored procedure is writing the data directly back to the database.